# How to implement Observable zip with Bifunction Single and Observable?

Tags: android, observable

How do I properly implement Observable.zip with Bifunction?

One returns a Single, one returns an Observable, not sure if this possible.

Thanks for the comment this is my updated. I'm not sure what to put in the BiFunction below

```
    Observable.zip(
            mCurrentUserViewModel.getUserProfile(getUserProfileRequest).toObservable(),
            mTopicsByCurrentUserViewModel.getTopicsByCreator(getTopicsByCreatorRequest)),
            new BiFunction<Single<GetUserProfileResponseBody>, Observable<Response<GetTopicsByCreatorResponseBody>>, **what do i put here**>()
    );
```

Comment: then add `.toObservable()` on the `Single`

Answer (score 1):

you have two options to do so.

`toSingle()` converts an Observable **which emits a single item** to a Single that emits this item

`toObservable` converts a Single into an Observable.

for example : using `toObservable()`

**1-create your observables**

```
private Observable<String> getObservable() {
    return Observable.just("observable");
}

private Single<String> singleObservable() {
    return Single.just("single");
}

private Observable<String> mergedObservable() {
    return Observable.zip(getObservable(), singleObservable().toObservable(), new BiFunction<String, String, String>() { //the result of merging is also String
        @Override
        public String apply(String s, String s2) {
            return s + s2;  //or if you are using different objects create a model AandB. where A and B are the result of a seperate observers.
        }
    });
}
```

**2-merge them**

```
           mergedObservable().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(new Observer<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(String s) {
                    Log.d(tag,s);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            });
```

**OUTPUT**:
`observablesingle`

Comment: I don't want to Merge the results, I want the getUserProfile and gettopics to be separate responses, I just want them to run at the same time so I can save time

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding here.to run two separate requests.just use subscribeOn().Zip is used to merge to result.

Answer (score 0):

an example zip function :

```
    private Observable<String> stringObservable() {
        return Observable.just("D");
    }

    private Observable<Integer> integerObservable() {
        return Observable.just(1);
    }

    private Observable<String> resultObservable(){
        return Observable.zip(stringObservable(), integerObservable(), new BiFunction<String, Integer, String>() {
            @Override public String apply(String s, Integer integer) throws Exception {
                return s + integer;
            }
        });
    }

    private Observable<String> resultObservableLambda(){
        return Observable.zip(stringObservable(), integerObservable(), (s, i) -> s + i);
    }
```

The 3rd item you are missing is your return type. So what is the aggregated type you want to return - in this example `String`, so a new Observable `Observable<String>` is returned.

Comment: I don't want to Merge the results, I want the getUserProfile and gettopics to be separate responses, I just want them to run at the same time so I can save time

Comment: Then look at the Rx operators and choose one that suits your needs, rather than asking a misleading question RE - Your question title.